# Bootstrap modal - alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

No matter what I try, the modal aligns halfway off the top of the page.  I am trying to open a modal from a button that's inside a table def.  It's the only modal on the page.

```
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##myModal">Click Here to Preview the Job Ad</button>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Don't put modals inside tables! ["Modal markup should not be placed within other components, so as to avoid the component's styles interfering with the modal's appearance or functionality"](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E022)

Answer (score 1):

That's the default position of the Modals in bootstrap.
However, you can change the position through CSS

Just add the following to your style for `modal-dialog`

```
style="position: fixed;  top: 50%;  left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"
```

Here's the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/PZ3TA6qZNc

Without `transform`, the positioning would appear something like this:

[image]